# 'Command not found' when trying to install Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, osx-mavericks, homebrew, bash

I'm having this issue when I try to install `Grunt`, I'm getting:

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
-bash: npm: command not found
```

I use `Homebrew` for intallations and as you can see on the list node is there:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.29
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
$ brew list
autoconf    jpeg        mhash       php55-mcrypt    zlib
fontconfig  libpng      mysql       pkg-config
freetype    libtiff     node        rbenv
gd          libtool     openssl     ruby-build
gettext     mcrypt      php55       unixodbc
```

This is the error I get after installing node(no idea what it mean):

```
..........

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
make[1]: *** [node_modules/.bin/ronn] Error 3
make: *** [man/man3/npm-bin.3] Error 2

..........
```

`==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.29: 1547 files, 18M`

Not sure but I think my problem is the `PATH` which I've been trying to fix with no success. This is my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:$(brew --prefix josegonzalez/php/php55)/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I'm confused! Any help here? Thanks.

Comment: did you try any of these suggestions? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3125

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `brew prune` made the trick:
I ran `brew uninstall node` and then `brew prune`, then `brew install node` and voilà! It allowed me to install`node` with no errors, `npm` also, and `grunt`.

Also, a recommended `worth to read` article I found: **http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html**